# How should I write the tag [word-choice] in Portuguese?

Tags: discussion, tags

A popular tag on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) is ["word-choice"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice). It refers to choosing, in sentence or context, between multiple words that could mean similar things.

It seems like the community is choosing Portuguese as the language for tags on this site. (For more discussion, see [Should we use English or Portuguese on tags?](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/112))

What's a good way to express "word choice" in Portuguese, for use as a tag? Have I missed an equivalent tag that people are already using?

Comment: This question is suitable for the main site, if you want to put it there, right? I was also wondering this yesterday, searching for a translation for "diction"

Comment: Perhaps *léxico*? The literal translation would be *escolha-de-palavras*, but its meaning isn't obvious.

Comment: In English this is considered a fundamental part of writing or speaking. I'm sure it's also discussed in the lusophone world, but I don't know what words they use to discuss it. I'm interested in learning both the best tag name and also how to discuss the phenomenon in Portuguese. So what's the correct etiquette? Should I have separate meta and non-meta questions pointing to each other? Should I migrate this to the main site? (At this stage, is it even possible to do migrations like that?)

Comment: @bfavaretto neither *léxico* for most people :)

Comment: Por enquanto tem o "uso-de-palavras".

Comment: Obrigado @BrunoLopes, me parece adequado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[uso-de-palavras](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palavras) seems to be the *de facto* choice.