# Essa [expression] não me expressa tão bem quanto essa [expressão]

Tags: support, tags

Bem, temos uma tag [expression](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression) e uma tag [expressão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/express%c3%a3o). A minha sugestão é que o nome das tags deve estar sempre em português (e estou usando esse caso como um precedente para definir desde já uma boa política de tags).

Desta forma, sugiro dar um *burninate* em todas as tags com nomes em inglês (ou qualquer outra língua que não o português) e manter apenas as tags em português. Exceto, é claro, se para alguma tag específica houver algum forte e justificável motivo em contrário, mas isso seriam casos isolados.

Outra opção seria fazer essas tags serem sinônimas.

Comment: Related, but not sure if duplicate: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1/57

Comment: It does seem to discuss the same topic of interest. Luckily, you might be able to move this question into an answer without changing much.

Comment: Yeah, I think this would make a good answer over on that other question. Personally, I prefer your second option (synonymization, over burnination).